# How to pass web service post method request body in fiddler

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, fiddler

I have a very simple web service in .net

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "xml?id={id}")]

string XMLData(string id);
```

When I am checking it in Fiddler by passing following URL,its working fine

```
http://localhost:60104/IO_100_Service.svc/xml?id=123}
```

but when I am passing the parameter in request body of fiddler its not working

```
URL
http://localhost:60104/IO_100_Service.svc/xml

Request Header
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Body
id=123
```

If anybody has any Idea about it, please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified URI template for your paramerter, threrfore to call this method you should request exactly that URL with parameter in it.

You can pass additionaly some data in body. But with such URI template paramter also should be passed through URI.

When you want you can change URI template and pass your data only on body

Comment: Thanks for your reply...U mean if I change my URI to UriTemplate = "xml" then I can pass my request parameter in the body,on changing URI and passing parameter in the request body of fiddler  id=2..it is showing bad request

Comment: Why you have made URL .../xml?id=123 and then try to call .../xml? Just use URL as you set by URI template

Comment: I think I am not able to explain my problem...Actually I jsut want to send request parameter in the request body not in the URL...How to achieve that?What will be my URI for that?